# Calculate delta between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to calculate delta between two tables. See the example:
First, I have tables A and B

table A

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Id 1 | 10 |
| Id 2 | 20 |
| Id 3 | 30 |
| Id 4 | 40 |

table B

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Id 1 | 10 |
| Id 2 | 15 |

So now in table B:

1. there is no Id 3 and Id 4 in B.
2. value of Id 2 differs.
3. id 1 is the same in both tables

What I need to do is to calculate table C which contains the difference between A and B

table C

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Id 2 | -5 |
| Id 3 | 30 |
| Id 4 | 40 |

There is no Id A in table C because it has same values in both A and B.

PostgreSQL DB.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible that Table B has ids missed in Table A is better to use FULL JOIN:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE C AS
SELECT coalesce(A.ID, B.ID) AS id,
       coalesce(B.Value, 0) - coalesce(A.Value, 0) AS Value
  FROM A
  FULL JOIN B ON
       A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Value IS DISTINCT FROM B.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Heres the query, I have tested it [here](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html).

```
INSERT INTO C (ID, Value)
SELECT A.ID, COALESCE(B.Value - A.Value, A.Value) AS Value
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.Value <> COALESCE(B.Value, A.Value) OR B.ID IS NULL;
```

**COALESCE:** Handle cases when there is no match in second table.

**Output:**
[image]

I am expecting you have already created table C.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both table always have the same columns, you can try the following approach -

```
-- Insert rows from table A where ID doesn't exist in table B
INSERT INTO C (ID, Value)
SELECT A.ID, A.Value
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL;

-- Insert rows from table B where ID exists in both tables A and B, but values are different
INSERT INTO C (ID, Value)
SELECT B.ID, B.Value - A.Value
FROM B
JOIN A ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.Value <> A.Value;
```